# JScrollPane prevents components shrinking below their preferred size

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, miglayout

I am using [`Miglayout`](http://www.miglayout.com/) to define a layout for my program. The problem is the `JScrollPane` prevents the JButton shrinking below its preferred size. The minimum, preferred, and maximum widths for the `JButton` are set like this, `"w 300:600:900" //min:pref:max`.

What is the best way to fix this problem?

**SSSCE**

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class ButLay extends JFrame {

    private ButLay()  {
        super("Button Layout");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new MigLayout("", "grow", "grow"));
        createPanel();
        setSize(800, 200);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new MigLayout("", "grow", "grow"));
    JScrollPane scroll;
    JButton button = new JButton("Button");

    private void createPanel() {
        panel.add(button, "gapleft 100, align right, w 300:600:900, south");
        scroll = new JScrollPane(panel);
        getContentPane().add(scroll, "grow");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ButLay();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default behaviour of a JScrollPane is to display the component in the scroll pane at its preferred size so that the scrollbars can appear as required.

If you want to change the behaviour then you can try to implement the `Scrollable` interface on your panel. You might be able to override the `getScrollableTracksViewportWidth()` method to return `true`. Now your panel should resize as the viewport of the scrollpane resizes. However using this approach your won't get a scrollbar if you make the viewport too small.

If you want the scrollbar in the above situation, then you may also need to override the `getPreferredSize()` method to return the minimum size when the preferredSize is greater than the size of the viewport.

You can also check out [Scrollable Panel](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/12/20/scrollable-panel/) which implements the `Scrollable` interface for you and allows you to customize the behaviour with some convenience methods.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will look into it. I did, however, change my approach to this as I realized my `JButton` did not need to be in the `JScrollPane` so I just docked it to the south of the JFrame