# Change background behind JTable TableHeaders

Tags: java, swing, background, jtable

I have an application with a few tables and a white application background to blend in with used logos. I have set all the backgrounds to white but there is one space that I could not reach so far.
With the standard JTable I am using it is possible to move columns and this is totally fine. However when moving the columns you are still able to see the standard applications color behind the TableHeaders. As displaying in a JScrollPane I thought setting the background of the `ScrollPane.getContentHeader()` would help but I get an NPE.

Below is a small program that should display the problem:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

public class testsforSO extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3890178393751567629L;
    private JTable table;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    testsforSO frame = new testsforSO();
                    frame.setSize(300, 300);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public testsforSO() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);



        String[] columns = new String[] { "ABC", "DEF", "XYZ" };
        TableModel tm = new DefaultTableModel(columns, 3);

        table = new JTable();
        table.setModel(tm);
        table.getTableHeader().setBackground(Color.WHITE); //Does its job
        table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
    }
}
```

When moving one of the three columns you will notice the standard background of your LAF (for me it is the Standard Windows LAF with its beige like color) instead of white eventhough the background of the TableHeader is set to white.
The color is set as well for the parts of the scrollPane width where no tableheaders are displayed and sets the color of the header to the correct color but I cannot figure out how to do so for the space behind the headers.

EDIT: After this seems to get misunderstood, I made a screen of my problem:

[image]

Unfortunately you cannot see the cursor, but I am holding the column at its header and dragging it to the right.

Comment: with your code i also get white space on the right of the tableheader

Comment: As said: "The color is set as well for the parts of the scrollPane width where no tableheaders are displayed" but I mean the space you can see when moving one of the columns from left to right and back.

Comment: as i understand it you want not just the tableheaders to have white background, but the whole window. try setting the content panes background to white

Comment: I tried `getContentPane().setBackround();` and `scrollPane.getViewPort().setBackground();` and `scrollPane.setBackground();` and `scrollPane.getColumnHeader().setBackground();` none of them worked, where the last one brings up an NPE. Edit: I gave a Color as parameter; no worries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> none of them worked, where the last one brings up an NPE.

The table header is not actually added to the frame until the frame is visible. At this time the scrollpane will get the table header from the table and add the header to the column header of the scrollpane.

So, AFTER the frame is visible you can do:

```
JTableHeader header = table.getTableHeader();
header.getParent().setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
```

So the above is required in addition to setting the four levels as suggested by @mKorbel.

You can also check out: [Setting JTableHeader holder background colour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40698612/setting-jtableheader-holder-background-colour/40709378#40709378) for a more detailed answer.

Comment: This looks promissing! I will have a look at that tomorrow when I am back on the project.

Comment: This definitely solves my problem! Thanks a lot. And another thanks for the reference on the other answer. I did not find that one...

Answer (score 5):

your problem are based on code line (because I think that `JTable` aren't designated to be non_resizable, maybe this is bug maybe its feature)

```
table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
```

you can to override this painting artefact by, then override the desired `Color` in `Renderer`

```
table.getTableHeader().setBackground(scrollPane.getBackground());
```

I'd be use `JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF`, in most case there isn't reason to be restricted to fixed size, my view is to use `LayoutManager` in all cases, without any restriction(s), e.g.

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40969405/change-background-behind-jtable-tableheaders

public class testsforSO extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3890178393751567629L;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    private String[] columns = new String[]{"ABC", "DEF", "XYZ"};
    private TableModel tm = new DefaultTableModel(columns, 3);
    private JTable table = new JTable(tm);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    testsforSO frame = new testsforSO();
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public testsforSO() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        String[] columns = new String[]{"ABC", "DEF", "XYZ"};
        TableModel tm = new DefaultTableModel(columns, 3);
        table.getTableHeader().setBackground(Color.WHITE); //Does its job
        table.getTableHeader().setBackground(scrollPane.getBackground());
        table.getTableHeader().setOpaque(true);
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        //table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
        add(scrollPane);
    }
}
```

EDIT

```
Try your program you gave as an answer (including scrollPane.getViewport().setBackground(Color.BLACK);) and run it. Black shows the problem better.
```

to see

[image]

from code (again to use Renderer for painting the Color inside JTables view)

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40969405/change-background-behind-jtable-tableheaders

public class testsforSO extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3890178393751567629L;
    private JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    private String[] columns = new String[]{"ABC", "DEF", "XYZ"};
    private TableModel tm = new DefaultTableModel(columns, 3);
    private JTable table = new JTable(tm);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    testsforSO frame = new testsforSO();
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public testsforSO() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        String[] columns = new String[]{"ABC", "DEF", "XYZ"};
        TableModel tm = new DefaultTableModel(columns, 3);
        //table.getTableHeader().setBackground(Color.WHITE); //Does its job
        table.getTableHeader().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        table.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
        scrollPane.getViewport().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
        add(scrollPane);
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not solve my problem unfortunately. Copying your code directly and commenting mine out results basically in the same problem described in my question. When moving the columns you can still see the old background.

Comment: you can to use `scrollPane.getViewport().setBackground(Color.WHITE);` in the case that `table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);` is necessary, again I'd not be to use `table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);`, let `Layout Manager` do own job (I think that do that and correctly)

Comment: I do not mean to be offending but it seems you did not understand what my problem is... Try your program you gave as an answer (including `scrollPane.getViewport().setBackground(Color.BLACK);`) and run it. Black shows the problem better. Now grab one column at the header and move it. You will notice that the part where the cells are, is totally black behind the table (the space that is only visible when moving the column) but the part where the headers are is still the default color.

Comment: there are four levels JTable, JTableHeader, JViewport, JScrollPane

Comment: I understand that! I have added a screenshot of my problem. Unfortunately you cannot see the cursor but imagine it holding the column and dragging it to the right.

Comment: (1+) but the trick is that the header is also added to a JViewport so the viewport of the header also needs to be set to the specified background color.